# Symfony 2 / Sonata / E-commerce routes issue

Tags: symfony, e-commerce, sonata

After installing Sonata Bundles with E-commerce bundles, I got this in backend

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("None of the chained routers were able to generate route: Route 'admin_app_commerce_customer_list' not found") in SonataAdminBundle:Block:block_stats.html.twig at line 25.
```

It seems like routes are missing, but I can't find anything in documentation related to that. All the routes from documentation are set.

Comment: did you install assets and cleared cache after the installation of the bundle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in cache...I missed that because composer cleared the cache after bundle installation...but it seems some parts stayed in cache. After I manually deleted cache...all is OK.